# AEM6, json drop-down: want to populate only value in drop down and not text

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have a json structure as follows:
[{"text":"US","value":"United Sates"},{"text":"CA","value":"Canada"}]

I have created a servlet to populate dropdown to a component.
My servlet:

```
           while (node.hasNext()) {
            Node child = node.nextNode();
            if (child.hasProperty("nationcode") && child.hasProperty("nationname")) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("text", child.getProperty("nationcode").getValue().getString());
                json.put("value", child.getProperty("nationname").getValue().getString());
                jsonArray.put(json);
            }
        }
```

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());

my component has options="bin/"

I try to populate only value but it could only populate "text" in the drop down. How do I make sure that my component drop-down only populates values but not keys(text) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented a similar approach and remember rendering the format you showed did not work. I think I pulled up the format that geometrixx uses in its dropdown (not sure of exact path)

The JSON format I used as response was

```
[{"text":"US","value":"United States","qtip":""}, {"text":"CA","value":"Canada","qtip":""}]
```

Once I had the list of required details
I used below for rendering required JSON format

```
for (Object object : allObjects) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        jsonOut.put("qtip", "");
                        jsonOut.put("text", object.getTitle());
                        jsonOut.put("value", object.getDescription());
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                        log.debug("jsonOut is {}", jsonOut);
                    }
                    }
```

That worked for me.

Comment: hey, so far it worked fine. How about putting it into a jsonArray and populating drop down with only "value" and not text.

Comment: I am not sure I tried that after I got what I wanted :D. Does it work for you? (Not too hopeful though). Please mark as answered if you feel this worked for you :)